# why my variable "j" is undefined?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function to color my 3D object using Three.js. My variable `j` exist, if I use `alert(j)` it works but when I use the variable as index of my array (colormap) it doesn't.

```
colormap=[[0,0,0.5625],[0,0,0.625],[0,0,0.6875],[0,0,0.75],[0,0,0.8125],[0,0,0.875],[0,0,0.9375],[0,0,1],[0,0.0625,1],[0,0.125,1],[0,0.1875,1],[0,0.25,1],[0,0.3125,1],[0,0.375,1],[0,0.4375,1],[0,0.5,1],[0,0.5625,1],[0,0.625,1],[0,0.6875,1],[0,0.75,1],[0,0.8125,1],[0,0.875,1],[0,0.9375,1],[0,1,1],[0.0625,1,0.9375],[0.125,1,0.875],[0.1875,1,0.8125],[0.25,1,0.75],[0.3125,1,0.6875],[0.375,1,0.625],[0.4375,1,0.5625],[0.5,1,0.5],[0.5625,1,0.4375],[0.625,1,0.375],[0.6875,1,0.3125],[0.75,1,0.25],[0.8125,1,0.1875],[0.875,1,0.125],[0.9375,1,0.0625],[1,1,0],[1,0.9375,0],[1,0.875,0],[1,0.8125,0],[1,0.75,0],[1,0.6875,0],[1,0.625,0],[1,0.5625,0],[1,0.5,0],[1,0.4375,0],[1,0.375,0],[1,0.3125,0],[1,0.25,0],[1,0.1875,0],[1,0.125,0],[1,0.0625,0],[1,0,0],[0.9375,0,0],[0.875,0,0],[0.8125,0,0],[0.75,0,0],[0.6875,0,0],[0.625,0,0],[0.5625,0,0],[0.5,0,0]];

j = 0;// indice colore nella matrice

var callbackMale = function ( geometry, materials ) 
{
  // surf contain surface
  var cmin=surf.min(), cmax=surf.max(), colorLength=colormap.length;

  for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) 
  {

     var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
     j = Math.round(((surf[i]-cmin)/(cmax-cmin)*colorLength));

     if(j < 0) 
      j=0;
     else if( j >= colorLength) 
       j=colorLength;
     alert(j)
     var ind = colormap[j]; // j undefined              
     for(var k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++)
     {              
       face.vertexColors[ k ] = new THREE.Color().setRGB(ind[0],ind[1],ind[2]);                 
     }//fine for interno

  }//fine for esterno
}
```

Comment: Spotted a small unrelated error: `if( j >= colorLength) j=colorLength;` should be `if( j >= colorLength) j=colorLength - 1;` or you will end up one past the last element of the array, since array indexes are zero-based.

Comment: it might be that result of your Math.round.. comes to be undefined

Comment: It is not j but colormap[j] that does not exist. if j = 9, colormap[9] does not exist.

Comment: I'd better make it an answer then. Maybe it wans't unrelated after all!

Comment: is your top `for loop` correct? shouldn't it be like `for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ )` ?

Comment: Why do you have to define j globally here ? Is there another piece of code that could modify it ?

Comment: @Kaf: that's the same logic, except the value of `geometry.vertices.length` is being stored in a local variable called `l` for a (very small) optimization.

Comment: @RenéWolferink: Thanks!, I had a little doubt.

Comment: Please don't put `[solved]` in title like as you would do in an old fashioned and cluttered discussion forum where you don't have insight in which questions are answered. This makes no sense here on a Q&A site where one can immediately see if a question is answered as questions having an accepted answer already appear differently in the listing.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of j? int or float or other ?
I think you try to put a float into a int and it doesn't work.

Comment: I use a Math.round that return an integer.

Comment: What's the value of 'j' with the alert ?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will run out of the bounds of your array, resulting in undefined values coming from `colormap[j]`.

```
else if( j >= colorLength) 
    j=colorLength;
```

puts your value jsut pas the bounds of your array, since arrays are zero-based. Fix the maximum to be one lower:

```
else if( j >= colorLength) 
    j=colorLength-1;
```